# Challenges in remotely running big RIA application

Tags: ajax, web-applications, executable-jar, qooxdoo

I have a big rich-internet-application file (qooxdoo,js,html). The users use their browser to point to the web server and run it. The problem is that it takes a long time for the users to load the application every time they visit the site.

Is there a way to somehow "**bundle**" and save the application locally and have the user refer to it locally? So, the url would be like [c:/]/home/myfiles/application/index.html instead of http://site/path-to-app?

I was thinking something like java's jar files to bundle the application and make it runnable locally in browsers, yet the application reaches the external website to get data.

Any ideas?!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The browser should cache all the files so the second load of the app should be quite fast. If thats not the case, maybe you are not using the qooxdoo build version of your application or you disabled the optimizations of the build process.

But there are two ways to get a desktop like application:

1. You can offer the files you upload to the server as zip and let the user unzip it. If you don't need a web server to run the files, that should work.
2. If you want to build a real desktop application, you should have a look at titanium [1] which can bring a webapp to the desktop.

[1] http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop/

Answer (score 2):

Running the qooxdoo application from the file system, like Martin sad, should not be a problem. But you have to ensure that "crossDomain" property for example "qx.io.remote.Request" [1] is set to "true", otherwise the same origin policy (SOP) from the Browser blocks the requests to the server.

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.io.remote.Request~crossDomain